# MYSQL error unknown column

Tags: php, mysql

```
UPDATE post_categories 
SET posts_counter = ".$sql_totalbooknumber." 
WHERE  `name` =  'Posts'
```

using the above query I keep getting Unknown column 'Posts' in 'where clause' MYSQL error

here is my $sql_totalbooknumber

$sql_totalbooknumber =  "SELECT SUM(posts_counter) FROM `post_categories` WHERE `posts_counter` > '0' AND `category_id` != '355'";

Comment: Can you show the *full* line of code as it exists in your PHP script? It's hard to decipher your quotes without it.

Comment: Are you sure that's the query as you've got it in your code?  WHERE "`name` = Posts" (missing quotes around string `Posts` would be one cause of that.

Comment: Where ``name`` just put without ` and change 'Posts' to "Posts". According to the error it seems like the value from the column name is not available. Can post the table here?

Comment: can you confirm the value in `$sql_totalbooknumber`? Is it properly escaped? Is it a string or a number?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
UPDATE post_categories 
SET posts_counter = '".$sql_totalbooknumber."' 
WHERE  `name` =  'Posts'
```

surround the value with single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Because variable `$sql_totalbooknumber` contains SQL SELECT query it must be put into brackets:

```php
    $sql_totalbooknumber = "SELECT SUM(posts_counter) FROM post_categories WHERE posts_counter > '0' AND category_id != '355'";
    
    $sql_query = "UPDATE post_categories 
    SET posts_counter = (".$sql_totalbooknumber.") 
    WHERE  `name` =  'Posts'";
```